# url to open facebook messenger app if installed, else open web messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I am looking for a single url to open facebook messenger chat session across different devices:

- On mobile, if fb messenger app is installed, it opens fb-messenger://user-thread/
- On mobile, if fb messenger app is not installed, it opens http://m.me/
- On desktop, it opens http://m.me/

Example: For Google map, I just need use `href="http://www.google.com/maps/place/{{lat}},{{lng}}"`, it will automatically open Google map app if installed, else it open google map on browser.

Answer (score 20):

```
http://m.me/<FACEBOOK_PAGE_USERNAME>
```

For example:

[Broadcast Football](https://m.me/broadcastfootball)

Comment: Is there any way to compose message content aswell through url

Comment: None that I know of, but I've not looked into this for quite a while.

Answer (score 2):

1. √ On mobile, if fb messenger app is installed, it opens fb-messenger://user-thread/
2. √ On mobile, if fb messenger app is not installed, it opens http://m.me/ **with call to action "install messenger"**
3. On desktop, it opens https://m.facebook.com/ (**bad because mobile**)

**In short you need to check if device is mobile or not:**

```
if(mobile) {
  <a href="https://m.facebook.com/messages/compose?ids=USER_NAME_OR_ID">messenger mobile test</a>
} else {
  <a href="https://m.me/USER_NAME_OR_ID">messenger desktop test</a>
}
```